Building a 16‘ x 24‘ workshop and plan on spray foam insulation for the entire building
I am very concerned about ventilation and also installing a mini split AC unit with a heat pump. Since this will be an airtight building with only a 6 foot wide rollup door and a walk-through door will I need additional ventilation methods? I do plan on running the mini split unit 24-7. I live in South Texas so it’s very hot and humid for eight months out of the year

What you should probably get is an Energy Recovery Ventilator (ERV) - which is a device that exchanges air in and out of the building via a heat and humidity exchanger, so outgoing cool dry air lowers the temperature and humidity of incoming hot wet air.
They come in various levels of efficiency and price.
In some climates a Heat Recovery Ventilator (HRV) (no humidity exchange) is preferable. Yours is not one, from the description in the question.
Shop carefully for the doors. The range of insulation values there is quite extreme, and with good insulation elsewhere they become a large part of the cooling (or heating) load if they are not well insulated themselves.

The main problem with an ERV or HRV in a shop space would be core clogging -- the OP may wish to have an extra filter on the exhaust duct in a place where it can be readily accessed for filter changes

It sounds as if you are building a giant foam cooler, yet are concerned about ventilation. This is a mutually exclusive situation.
Being the unit is used as a workshop you may be making fumes and /or dust. You should consider a ventilation / dust collection system. Without it the filter in the mini-split unit will become clogged very quickly.
The easiest solution would be a wall mounted exhaust fan. An equal sized shutter vent on the opposite wall will allow fresh air in. Mounting a filter in the vent and fan will get rid of outside particles as well as the stuff you produce inside.  ( A friend has this type of system for his custom clock and table business. Works great here in Fla.)  You turn it on when it is needed, or you can have it managed by a programer.
A small mini-split unit will cool the space easily and recover the temp. well after the fan is used.
